# Evaluate $\int_2^3 {\text{d}x\over x \log(x + 5)}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have this integral to solve. I have tried both integration by substitution and integration by parts but couldn't solve it.

> $$\int_2^3 {\text{d}x\over x \log(x + 5)}$$

How do i solve this?

Comment: There is no general rule; that is part of what makes integration difficult. However, in this case, might I suggest substitution?

Comment: acutally it is definite integral question from [2,3]. i have done the substitution u = log(x+5) but in the integral the `x` doesn't cancel out

Comment: This indefinite integral doesn't seem to have a simple expression by means of elementary functions...if only that $\;x\;$ was $\;x+5\;$, or that $\;x+5\;$ was $\;x\;$ , it'd be a ridiculously simple integral, though.

Comment: @Integrator Yeah his is the function that my teacher gave

Comment: @Timbuc: yeah I also thought that way may this question is wrong.

Comment: The deeper question is why someone would want to solve it. Because there are unlimited possibilities for "compute this integral" questions, we look for some motivation about why the integral in question is interesting or worth studying.

Comment: What substitutions have you tried? There are a few, and so that we don't duplicate your effort, it would be helpful if we could see what has already been tried.

Comment: @CarlMummert: The integral $$\int_2^3\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x\log(x)}=\log(\log(3))-\log(\log(2))$$ is fairly simple, but the change to $x+5$ requires some innovation. I guess I could add that to the question.