# Indefinite integral of $\frac{\sec^2x}{(\sec x+\tan x)^\frac{9}{2}}$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

$$\frac{\sec^2x}{(\sec x+\tan x)^\frac{9}{2}}$$

**My approach:**

Since it is easy to evaluate $\int{\sec^2x}$ , integration by parts seems like a viable option.

Let $$I_n=\int{\frac{\sec^2x}{(\sec x+\tan x)^\frac{9}{2}}}$$

$$I_n=\frac{\tan x}{(\sec x+\tan x)^\frac{9}{2}} + \frac{9}{2}\int{\frac{\sec x \tan x}{(\sec x+\tan x)^\frac{9}{2}}dx}$$

Evaluating the new integral again using by parts yields

$$\frac{\sec x}{(\sec x+\tan x)^\frac{9}{2}}+\frac{9}{2}\int{\frac{\sec^2x}{(\sec x+\tan x)^\frac{9}{2}}\,dx}$$

$$=\frac{\sec x}{(\sec x+\tan x)^\frac{9}{2}} + \frac{9}{2} I_n$$

Plugging it back, we obtain
$$I_n=\frac{\tan x}{(\sec x+\tan x)^\frac{9}{2}} + \frac{9}{2}\frac{\sec x}{(\sec x+\tan x)^\frac{9}{2}} + \frac{81}{4}I_n $$

$$\frac{-77}{4}I_n=\frac{\tan x}{(\sec x+\tan x)^\frac{9}{2}} + \frac{9}{2}\frac{\sec x}{(\sec x+\tan x)^\frac{9}{2}}$$

This obviously doesn't match with [bprp's answer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ar2FyETzKU8). Help!

***Edit:***
How do I convert my answer to the answer obtained by him, if mine is correct

Comment: Your answer is correct but not in the desired form.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1054719/evaluating-int-frac-sec2-x-sec-x-tan-x-9-2-mathrm-dx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluating $\int \frac{\sec^2 x}{(\sec x + \tan x )^{{9}/{2}}}\,\mathrm dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1054719/evaluating-int-frac-sec2-x-sec-x-tan-x-9-2-mathrm-dx)

Comment: I have edited the question asking for help to transform my result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$-77I_n=4 \times \frac{\tan x}{(\sec x+\tan x)^\frac{9}{2}} + 18 \times \frac{\sec x}{(\sec x+\tan x)^\frac{9}{2}}$

$-77I_n= 11 \times \frac{\tan x}{(\sec x+\tan x)^\frac{9}{2}} - 7 \times \frac{\tan x}{(\sec x+\tan x)^\frac{9}{2}} + 11 \times \frac{\sec x}{(\sec x+\tan x)^\frac{9}{2}} + 7 \times \frac{\sec x}{(\sec x+\tan x)^\frac{9}{2}}$

$-77I_n= 11 \times \frac{\sec x+\tan x}{(\sec x+\tan x)^\frac{9}{2}} + 7 \times \frac{\sec x - \tan x}{(\sec x+\tan x)^\frac{9}{2}}$

First part is straightforward. The second part can be simplified multiplying both numerator and denominator by $(\sec x+\tan x)$. We know, $(\sec x+\tan x) (\sec x-\tan x) = 1$.

You can take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

You missed a simplification after second step:

$$I=\frac{\tan x}{(\sec x+\tan x)}\frac{9}{2}+\frac{9}{2}\int \frac{\sec x \tan x}{(\sec x+\tan x)^{\frac92}}dx$$

Now, take the original expression for $I$

$$ I = \int \frac{\sec^2 x}{(\sec x + \tan x)^{\frac92}}$$

Add this $ \frac{9}{2} $ times this  to previous expression

$$ \frac{11}{2} I = \frac{\tan x}{(\sec x+\tan x)}\frac{9}{2}+\frac{9}{2}\int \frac{\sec x \tan x + \sec^2 x}{(\sec x+\tan x)^{\frac92}}dx$$

Consider the second integral:

$$ J = \int \frac{\sec x \tan x + \sec^2 x}{(\sec x+\tan x)^{\frac92}}dx$$
Substitute $ \sec x + \tan x = t$

$$ J = \int t^{-\frac92} dt$$

Done!